# возможно ли два запроса выборки заменить одним?

Tags: mysql, sql

возникла мысль заменить два запроса к базе одним, возможно ли такое сделать?

```
SELECT  `label` AS  `from` FROM  `city` WHERE  `code` =  'moscow'
SELECT  `label` AS  `to` FROM  `city` WHERE  `code` =  'irkutsk'
```

Результат который нужно получить одним запросом должен быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо получить две строки или две колонки в одной строке?

Comment: две колонки с разными строками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятна БД, которая у вас. При объединении может получиться нежелаемый результат, поэтому запросы могут быть не совсем корректны.

Как вариант, можно объединить 2 запроса через `UNION` (1 столбец, строки друг под другом):

```
SELECT  `label` AS  `from` FROM  `city` WHERE  `code` =  'moscow'
UNION
SELECT  `label` AS  `to` FROM  `city` WHERE  `code` =  'irkutsk'
```

Можно сделать так, чтобы было 2 столбца `label` - `to` и `from`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT  `label` AS  `from` FROM  `city` WHERE  `code` =  'moscow') c1,
     (SELECT  `label` AS  `to` FROM  `city` WHERE  `code` =  'irkutsk') c2
```

Answer (score 2):

В случае, если вас устроит две возвращаемые строки, в первом столбце которых будет указан город, можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT `code`, `label` FROM  `city` WHERE `code` IN('moscow', 'irkutsk')
```

Если строка должна быть одна, можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  from.label AS from,
  to.table AS to
FROM
  (SELECT `label` FROM `city` WHERE `code` = 'moscow' LIMIT 1) AS from
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT `label` FROM `city` WHERE `code` = 'irkutsk' LIMIT 1) AS to
```

Comment: Может получиться нежелаемый результат (лишние строки) - может попасться label, где from = moscow

Comment: @Denis Вы правы, привел альтернативный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Из запроса:

```
SELECT `code`, `label` 
FROM  `city` WHERE `code` IN('moscow', 'irkutsk')
```

В других СУБД можно получить одну строку простым `PIVOT`.

Но у вас `MySQL`, так что можно поступить вот так:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(IF(`code`='moscow',`label`,null)) as `from`,
  MAX(IF(`code`='irkutsk',`label`,null)) as `to`
FROM `city` WHERE `code` IN('moscow', 'irkutsk')
```